# What the option full is doing on [full]{textcomp}?

Tags: packages, textcomp

Looking over the package `textcomp` source code, I cannot find any option declared with the name `full`. Why and what is this full doing?

http://www.cs.cmu.edu/afs/cs/misc/tex/common/teTeX-1.0/lib/texmf/tex/latex/base/textcomp.sty

Comment: You provided a link to a quite old version `1999/12/08 v1.9x`. You'll find the option in an actual version.

Comment: Thanks! But where I can find the new version? I see it is bounded with LaTeX, but it is available online?

Comment: I found it on my computer at: `D:\latex\texmfs\install\tex\latex\base\textcomp.sty`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is described in [The LaTeX 2ε Sources documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/base/source2e.pdf):

> **The `textcomp` package**
>
> (…)
>   The options for the package are the following:
>
> - **safe** for unknown font families enables only symbols that are also in the ISO-Adobe character set; without “currency”, which is often misused for the Euro. Older Type1 fonts from the non-TeX world provide only this subset.
> - **euro** enables the “safe” symbols plus the `\texteuro` command. Most newer fonts
>     provide this.
> - **full** enables all `TS1` commands; useful only with fonts like EC or CM bright.
> - **almostfull** same as “\full”, except that `\textcircled` and `\t` are *not* redefined from their defaults to avoid that commands like `\copyright` suddenly no
>     longer work.
> - **force** ignore all subset encoding definitions stored in the package itself or in the configuration file and always use the default subset as specified by one of the other options (seldom useful, only dangerous).

Comment: What are TS1 commands?

Comment: @user Those defined in the file `ts1enc.def`, that is, the LaTeX internal character representation (LICR) of the characters in the TS1 encoding.